# Help With Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I'm not so good with regex, and need some help.

I have a string similar to the following:

```
[{type='(type here)', field='(field here)', value='(value here)'},{...},...,{...}]
```

I am trying to match it with the following regex:

```
^\[(\{type=\'(.*)\', field=\'(.*)\', value=\'(.*)\'\},*)*\]$
```

But it isn't matching. I then debugged. Here is the regex I used for debugging:

```
\[(\{(.*)\}\]
```

Here is the string:

```
[{type='cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'},{type='cost', field='29 versions', value='250'}]
```

Here is the match:

{type='cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'},{type='cost', field='29 versions', value='250'}

I understand why this string was matched. I do not understand why *no other strings were matched*.  I expected the other matched strings to be:

1. {type='cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'},
2. {type='cost', field='29 versions', value='250'}

Why were these matches not made?

Comment: You might want to point out what application / programming language you are using (Notepad++, Perl, C#...?). They all have slightly different syntax when it comes to regexes

Comment: Using javascript string.match(), but I omitted the // surrounding the regex. I was actually just testing it here: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Comment: Delimiters shouldn't affect anything as long as he's not using possessive quantifiers -- the regex should consume more in order to match the rest of the pattern. Also, that `'` in `$1/M's`should probably be escaped. :P

Comment: @BlackSheep: Do you want to parse the subgroups or just split them (those curly embraced portions)? Your question of the "Why" has been answered, but I am curious ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using `.*` inside the subgroups. The `type=\'(.*)\'` matches greedily, i.e. it will yield `cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'}, {type='cost`.

Also: The delimiters in your data are also present in the content, e.g. your pattern seeks to parse `field=\'(.*)\'` but hits hard onto `field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)',` (note the extra `'`after the M.

So I propose (if you also want to collect the content of the fields):

1. Watch the possible content of your "fields", to shield the subgrouping (escape or find better delimiters, if data comes from external source).
2. Avoid greediness like Steve Wang mentions in his answer, to collect the subgroups only as intended.

otherwise, trigger only on the curly brace grouping, i.e. `\{[^\}]+\}`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
^ matches at the start of the string
\[ matches "["
(
    \{type=\' matches "{type='"
    (
        .* matches "cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'},{type='cost"
    ) captures "cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'},{type='cost"
    \', field=\' matches ', field='
    (
        .* matches "29 versions"
    ) captures "29 versions"
    \', value=\' matches "', value='"
    (
        .* matches "250"
    ) captures "250"
    \'\} matches "'}"
    ,* matches ""
)* captures "{type='cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'},{type='cost', field='29 versions', value='250'}" (first and only repeat)
\] matches "]"
$ matches at the end of the string
```

Therefore group 1 captures everything between "[" and "]".

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you're using a greedy quantifier as opposed to a lazy one. Insert a `?` after each of your `*`'s and see if that fixes anything.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
    var str = "[{type='cost', field='flag & e band 100s ($1/M's)', value='680'},{type='cost', field='29 versions', value='250'}] ";
    var regexp = /\{[^\}]+\}/g;
    var m;
    while (m = regexp.exec(str)) {
        alert(m[0]);
    }
```

The expression definitely doesn't have to be too complex - `/\{[^\}]+\}/g` means:

globally, (the g after the closing forward slash), give me everything that starts with a {, has one or more non-} characters, and ends with }.